# How to pick images from Gallery instead of Photos in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I am using the following code to pick images.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)), 1);
```

Its working fine but it only let me to choose images from default Photos application. I want to pick images from "Gallery" application even in today's latest devices. I don't know how **WhatsApp** is doing this even for **Lollipop**.

Answer (score 0):

I am using This code in my app and it works fine for me..

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/* video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

Comment: does it launches Gallery App or Photos App from Google plus ?

Comment: In emulator Gallery is exist. so it launches Gallery App.

Comment: Actually my issue is, Photos app shows some images from cache directory too, and i dnt want to bee seen. Gallery app does not do this.

Comment: What if there is no gallery app.